# Typed generic wont call method with correct param type, always calls with object

Tags: c#, generics

I would expect below to call the overloaded write method with an `int` as Test is typed to `TValue` (which on instance is an int type). But for some reason it just keeps calling the `object` write method signature.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how can I actually call the correct method without casting.

```
class Test<TValue>
{
    private readonly Func<TValue> _valueExpression;

    public Test(Func<TValue> valueExpression)
    {
        _valueExpression = valueExpression;
    }

    public void Write(Writer writer)
    {
        writer.Write(_valueExpression.Invoke());
    }
}

class Writer
{
    public void Write(int val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrote int");
    }

    public void Write(object val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrote object");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test<int>(() => 4);

        test.Write(new Writer());
        // always returns "wrote object"

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The method to use is chosen at compile time. The overload with an int parameter is not an option at that moment since T is not convertable to an int since it is an open generic T, not a closed one where it is an int (as in your case).

Comment: Cheers :). think I'm just going to stick with object for this one. I was trying to make something more performant by removing type casting but seems dynamic is far slower than a cast.